# Microsoft Excel Dropdown reaction to column

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Excel table]

Hi All,

I have a table similar to the image. It has a dropdown list under every column with the same values. What I am trying to achieve is that if the Dropdown option is selected then it should check the name in row A18 (the same row the dropdown is in) and see if that name exists in the column above. If the name exists then either cause an alert or remove the name from that column preferably. Is it possible? Please let me know.
Many thanks in advance,

Comment: You can show an alert in another cell by formula before or after selection in dropdown, but a true alert pop-up and removal from the list both require vba

Comment: i was dreading that VBA will be needed to accomplish that task.  many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the following code in your worksheet code pane

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim nameCel As Range
        Select Case True
            Case target.CountLarge > 1
            
            Case Not IsThereValidation(target)
                       
            Case Not IsThereName(target, nameCel)
            
            Case Else
                nameCel.ClearContents
        End Select
    
End Sub

Function IsThereName(target As Range, nameCel As Range) As Boolean
    Set nameCel = Range(Cells(1, target.Column), target.Offset(-1)).Find(what:=Cells(target.Row, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    IsThereName = Not nameCel Is Nothing
End Function

Function IsThereValidation(target As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsThereValidation = target.Validation.Type <> 0
End Function
```

Comment: modular approach is appreciable. Many thanks,

Comment: you are welcome
if this solved your question then please mark the answer as accepted
this will both help future readers and please me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            ' Change on Col D
            If .Column = 4 And Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                ' Check if target has data validation
                On Error Resume Next
                Dim vDataVal
                vDataVal = .Validation.Type
                If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Sub
                On Error GoTo 0
                Dim arrData, i As Long, sName As String
                ' Get all names in Col D
                arrData = Range("D1:D" & .Row - 1).Value
                ' The Name in current row
                sName = Cells(.Row, 1).Value
                For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
                    If StrComp(arrData(i, 1), sName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        Application.EnableEvents = False
                        ' Remove same name from upper cells
                        Cells(i, "D").ClearContents
                        Application.EnableEvents = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [StrComp function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009035)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)